# sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -f pathname throws invalid_grant

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have successfully authorized my sandbox org via this command:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a MyAliasName
```

And then fired this command to fetch AccessToken and ClientId to create SFDX auth url:

```
C:\Users\****>sfdx force:org:display -u MyAliasName
=== Org Description
KEY               VALUE
────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Access Token      **********************************************************************C4.flcgGfDL1zOiD
Alias             MyAliasName
Client Id         PlatformCLI
Connected Status  Connected
Id                00D54000000*********
Instance Url      https://******-dev-ed.cs40.my.salesforce.com
Username          nagendra.singh@******
```

Even then the force cli connected app is not appearing in the list :

[image]

Then I created `force://` url with the details above.

`force://PlatformCLI::<ACESS_TOKEN>://<INSTANCEURL>` and stored it in a file.

Then after firing this command I get `invalid_grant` issue:

```
C:\Users\***\Downloads>sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -f AuthURL.txt
ERROR running force:auth:sfdxurl:store:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - expired access/refresh token
username: <Not Specified>,
clientId: <Not Specified>,
loginUrl: <Not Specified>,
privateKey: <Not Specified>
```

Any step I missed or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its documented anywhere but the `SFDX Auth URL` does not use  to build the URL.

When I fired with `sfdx force:org:display -u MyAliasName --verbose`

Then it gave this :

```
=== Org Description
KEY               VALUE
────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Access Token      .<AuthURL>
Alias             MyAliasName
Client Id         PlatformCLI
Connected Status  Connected
Id                *****
Instance Url      https://*******
Sfdx Auth Url     force://PlatformCLI::NotAuthURL@*******
Username          nagendra.singh@*****
```

here when I compared the `accesstoken` and `notauthurl` value, then it was not same, so probably it gives refresh token or so.

Answer (score 0):

[SF documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_auth_sfdxurl.htm#cli_reference_auth_sfdxurl_store) states that the file must store the ***Refresh Token***  (NOT ***Access Token***).

```
Authorize a Salesforce org using an SFDX auth URL stored within a file. 
The file must have the format "force://<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl>" or "force://<clientId>:<clientSecret>:<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl>".

The file must contain only the URL or be a JSON file that has a top-level property named sfdxAuthUrl.
```

I'm able to use the command without any issues. In fact, command `sfdx force:org:display` returns the value for `Sfdx Auth Url`, which can be stored in the file. If you are unable to get `Sfdx Auth Url` as one of the return values for this display command, check your SFDX version # or run `sfdx update` before running this command.

Comment: I was following one of the blogs and got confused https://medium.com/@medben/sfdx-org-authorization-%EF%B8%8F-a75b54861b54, here it said <access_token>, thanks for documentation,